# tikzpicture graph self loop showing arrow-tip in both directions

Tags: tikz-arrows

I have the following `tikzpicture`,

```
\tikzset{every picture/.style={line width=0.75pt}} 
\begin{tikzpicture}[x=0.6pt,y=0.6pt,yscale=-1,xscale=1, 
  main/.style = {draw, circle, 
  fill={rgb, 255:red, 0; green, 0; blue, 0 }},
  text=white,
  node distance=3cm,
  ->,
  >={Stealth[round,sep]}]
  \node[main] (1) {$s$};
  \node[main] (2) [right of=1]{$v_1$};
  \node[main] (3) [right of=2]{$v_2$};
  \node[main] (4) [right of=3]{$v_n$};
  \node[main] (5)[right of=4]{$t$};
  \node[text=black] at ($(3)!.5!(4)$) {\ldots};
  \draw (1) -- (2) node[midway, below, text=black]{$s_1$};
  \draw (2) -- (3) node[midway, below, text=black]{$s_1$};
  \draw (4) -- (5) node[midway, below, text=black]{$s_1$};
  \draw (2) edge[bend left] node[near start, above, text=black]{$s_0$} (1);
  \draw (3) edge[bend left] node[near start, above, text=black]{$s_0$}(1);
  \draw (4) edge[bend left] node[near start, above, text=black]{$s_0$}(1);
  \draw (1.south) edge[bend right=120, min distance=1.6cm] node[near start, below, text=black]{$s_0$} (1.north);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

which renders,
[image: resultant graph]
I'm not exactly sure how to stop the arrow tip being rendered on both sides of the edge from s to s.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Replace `edge` with `to`. Also, in the future, always provide a ["Minimal Working Example" (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that starts with `\documentclass`, includes all relevant `\usepackage` commands, ends with `\end{document}` and compiles without errors, even if it does not produce your desired output.

Comment: Besides using `to` instead of `edge`, you ought to be using `\path` instead of `\draw` for the edges, but since you don't draw multiple edges on one `\path`, using `to` is marginally better. You can also set `tips=on proper draw` which will remove that up arrow from the otherwise empty path.